# want to select option from dropdown and change title of button according to selected option ...How?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

For  dropdrawn menu ,i used UItableView and button to display dropdown list  when i select option from dropdown i want to change title of button according to selected option ??

// foodbutton click

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foodcell", for: indexPath)

   // cell.textLabel?.text = array [indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = array [indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


@nonobjc func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    selectFoodbutton.setTitle(cell?.textLabel?.text, for: .normal)
    self.foodtable.isHidden = true
}


@IBAction func selectFoodbutton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.foodtable.isHidden = !self.foodtable.isHidden
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In button action write the code for appear the table view like below way.

First u create a tableview below that button.
load datasource into that tableview.
then select the one of the cell.
then set the button title as selected one.
then finally hide the table view.

code snippet like this

```
@IBAction func educationBtnAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    //    let point = textfield.getBottomTableViewPoint()
    let point = sender.getPointBased(level: 1)
    self.educationTableview = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: point.x, y: point.y, width: sender.frame.size.width + 10, height: 150), style: .plain)
    self.educationTableview.dataSource = self
    self.educationTableview.delegate  = self
    self.educationTableview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.educationTableview.applyPropertiesToPopupTableView()
    //  textfield.superview?.addSubview(labPanelTableView)
    bgScrollView.addSubview(educationTableview)

    if self.educationTableview.alpha == 0.0{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.hidePopups()
            self.educationTableview.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: { finished in
        })
    }
    commonTypeArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5",]
    self.educationTableview.reloadData()
```

}

```
func hidePopups() {
    self.educationTableview.alpha = 0.0
}
```

For remaining process your code above in question is enough

Comment: selectFoodbutton.setTitle(cell?.textLabel?.text, for: .normal)...is this code not enough to change the label of button??